# What does `application-specific imports` means in Google Python Style Guide

Tags: python, google-style-guide

In the section, [Imports Formatting](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#313-imports-formatting), of Google Python Style Guide, the fourth point which is about application-specific imports is [marked as deprecated in Nov. 2018](https://github.com/google/styleguide/commit/ad22a7536d9cbc552c2d265d5df18be9b1b24faa#diff-10d4489c6eaf41e45c2401481f43ef9c). The example in the section does not provide enough information to understand what formatting should replace the old one. The lines indicated as the old style appear in both commented and uncommented format!

Take the example in the Style Guide.

```py
from myproject.backend.hgwells import time_machine
from myproject.backend.state_machine import main_loop
```

Are these two lines good? If not, what should replace them?